# Postgres: ERROR: value too long for type character varying(255) Does not specify the field

Tags: postgresql

I am getting this error occasionally and obviously I need to change the type from string to text, but the logs do not show which column is the culprit. Below is log from resque which is the most detailed error output but it is a large table and the sql output changes from error to error and is just a small portion of the entire update sql. Any ideas on how to figure out which column the error is referring to?

> PG::StringDataRightTruncation: ERROR: value too long for type character varying(255) : UPDATE "listings" SET "created_at" = $1, "date_posted" = $2, "google_map_link" = $3, "phone" = $4, "acency_id" = $5, "updated_at" = $6 WHERE "listings"."id" = 392998

Comment: Wrap that statement in an exception handler and inspect the exception to see if it tells you anything more. What does `listings` look like? The only obvious `varchar(255)` would be `google_map_link`.

Comment: Are you on an old PostgreSQL version? IIRC current versions specify the field affected.

Comment: I am running PG Version: 9.3.4 on Heroku. Been looking like crazy and still no indication of which field is the offender.

Comment: I know I am way too late but maybe just manually check each possible field one at a time with a string of over 255.

Answer (score 1):

I work almost exclusively with large numbers of text files in Django. I set up a dict to mirror the database columns, ie: dict['good_column'].
Then in my try/except, I added that to the end of my logger.warning("You screwed something up: ".format(dict['good_column']). That way, the log tells me exactly where to look for the problem. I assume Ruby has some equivalent constructs to do this with.

Comment: This is a great idea!