# Django Postgres old model persisting value too long for type character varying(25)

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-1.6

I have a twitter API project that works fine on my localhost (SQLite3) and on an existing server (Postgres).  I'm migrating it to DigitalOcean (also Postgres) and now hitting this error:  `value too long for type character varying(25)`   I understand what the error means, but feel as though the steps I've taken should have changed it.

I don't want to truncate the data [(as suggested here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747922/value-too-long-for-type-character-varyingn), so want to able to read in whatever is throwing the error, and this same code works on another server (Centos6), but not on DO (Debian).  Both are running PostGres 9.3.4, and both are encoding in UTF8 (the locale on the Debian server is also set correctly, as I believe this can cause problems.)  The templates from the debian server look like this:

```
                                 List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
(3 rows)
```

Thinking that I was getting some erroneous data in, I changed away from CharFields, to TextFields with no limit, but still hitting the error - in any case, it's not intermittent, it's *every* tweet that's hitting the Exception.  Oddly, it specifies 'for type character varying(25)', which is an OLD version of the limit I had a while back - but I've dropped the database (multiple times...) in psql and checked that the correct version of the code is deployed on the server.

[I had a similar problem to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305718/postgres-error-value-too-long-for-type-character-varying255-does-not-specify) guy in debugging, in that I don't know which field it is that's throwing the error, but on closer inspection in psql, I got the table info:

```
                                Table "public.harvester_tweet"
          Column           |           Type           |                          Modifiers                           
---------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------
 id                        | integer                  | not null default nextval('harvester_tweet_id_seq'::regclass)
 truncated                 | boolean                  | not null
 text                      | text                     | not null
 in_reply_to_status_id     | bigint                   | 
 favorite_count            | integer                  | not null
 author_id                 | integer                  | not null
 _json                     | text                     | not null
 source                    | character varying(25)    | not null
 retweeted                 | boolean                  | not null
 coordinates               | text                     | 
 entities                  | text                     | 
 in_reply_to_screen_name   | character varying(25)    | 
 id_str                    | character varying(25)    | not null
 retweet_count             | integer                  | not null
 favorited                 | boolean                  | not null
 retweeted_status          | text                     | not null
 user                      | text                     | 
 geo                       | text                     | 
 in_reply_to_user_id_str   | character varying(25)    | 
 possibly_sensitive        | boolean                  | not null
 lang                      | character varying(5)     | not null
 created_at                | timestamp with time zone | not null
 in_reply_to_status_id_str | character varying(25)    | 
 place                     | text                     |
```

Models.py

```
class Tweet(models.Model):
    truncated=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    text=models.TextField()
    in_reply_to_status_id=models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    favorite_count=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    _json = models.TextField()
    source=models.TextField()
    retweeted=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    coordinates = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    entities = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    in_reply_to_screen_name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    id_str = models.TextField()
    retweet_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    favorited = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    retweeted_status = models.TextField()
    user = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True) #User is a dictionary in the response; here we take a serialised version
    geo = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    in_reply_to_user_id_str = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    possibly_sensitive = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    lang = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    in_reply_to_status_id_str = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    place = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode("@" + (self.author.screen_name) + " " + str(self.created_at))
```

The code that reads it in is here:

```
def read_tweet(tweet_data, current_user):
    import logging
    logger = logging.getLogger('django')
    from datetime import date, datetime
    #print "Inside read_Tweet"
    from harvester.models import Tweet
    from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
    from django.db import DataError
    #We might get weird results where user has changed their details"], so first we check the UID.
    #print tweet_data["created_at"]
    from dateutil.parser import parse
    tweet_data["created_at"] = parse(tweet_data["created_at"])
    try:
        #print "trying tweet_data["id"
        current_tweet =Tweet.objects.get(id_str=tweet_data["id_str"])
        created=False
        return current_user, created
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        pass

    try:
        current_tweet, created = Tweet.objects.get_or_create(
        truncated=tweet_data["truncated"],
        text=tweet_data["text"],
        favorite_count=tweet_data["favorite_count"],
        author = current_user,
        _json = {},
        source=tweet_data["source"],
        retweeted=tweet_data["retweeted"],
        coordinates = tweet_data["coordinates"],
        entities = tweet_data["entities"],
        in_reply_to_screen_name = tweet_data["in_reply_to_screen_name"],
        id_str = tweet_data["id_str"],
        retweet_count = tweet_data["retweet_count"],
        favorited = tweet_data["favorited"],
        user = tweet_data["user"],
        geo = tweet_data["geo"],
        in_reply_to_user_id_str = tweet_data["in_reply_to_user_id_str"],
        lang = tweet_data["lang"],
        created_at = tweet_data["created_at"],
        place = tweet_data["place"])
        print "DEBUG", current_user, current_tweet
        return current_tweet, created
    except DataError, e:
        #Catchall to pick up non-parsed tweets
        print "DEBUG ERROR", e, tweet_data
        return None, False
```

I dropped the DB in psql `drop database name;`, and then recreated it, ran syncdb and migrate in south (i'm still on 1.6 for a variety of reasons) - why is that still there?

Edit:  I"ve just triple checked this, changed the database entirely, created a new one under a different name, and it's still like this!  What am I missing?  I've gone in on the server and looked in models.py and they're as shown here, I'm baffled.

Second edit:  After having gone in and run schemamigration, it's now working (gah!), but I'd still like to understand the behaviour here, as it wasn't what I was expecting.

Comment: If you look into your migrations directory, could you check the file dates to each migration? Most times you can tell by the name of the migration what change in the model it reflects. The migration that extends the `max_length` that caused the exception, has it a file date from today when you ran `schemamigration` or does it have an older file date?

Comment: The change to working was today, the other one (there are only two), the intiial one was dated 2 days ago.  I guess that's the surprise for me here - even though I've dropped the DB and am rebuilding it, unless I delete the South migrations as well, it'll go back to the last accepted migration?

Comment: Yes, once one starts working with migrations for an app they become a vital and persistent part (= under version control) of the project. Running `migrate` relies on all migrations being available in the directory. While in development deleting migrations before dropping the DB is perfectly fine. But once the app is shared by more developers or deployed somewhere keeping the migrations is critical.