# How to determine which column is implicated in "value too long for type character varying"?

Tags: postgresql

I'm programatically adding data to a PostgreSQL table using Python and psycopg - this is working fine.

Occasionally though, a text value is too long for the containing column, so I get the message:

> ERROR: value too long for type character varying(1000)

where the number is the width of the offending column.

Is there a way to determine **which column** has caused the error? (Aside from comparing each column's length to see whether it is 1000)

Comment: Check your query and your DDL

Comment: @frlan would that help in the case of an existing table though? Say I've already inserted 100 records successfully and record 101 causes the problem - how can I tell which part of my INSERT statement is too long?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many thanks to @Tometzky, whose comment pointed me in the right direction.

Rather than trying to determine which column caused the problem *after* the fact, I modified my Python script to ensure that the value was truncated *before* inserting into the database.

1. access the table's schema using `select column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length from information_schema.columns where table_name='test'`
2. when building the INSERT statement, use the schema definition to identify character fields and truncate if necessary

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's an easy way.

I tried to set VERBOSITY in psql, as I assumed this would help, but unfortunately not (on 9.4):

```
psql
\set VERBOSITY verbose
dbname=>  create temporary table test (t varchar(5));
CREATE TABLE
dbname=> insert into test values ('123456');
ERROR:  22001: value too long for type character varying(5)
LOCATION:  varchar, varchar.c:623
```

This might be something that warrants discussion on the mailing list, as [you are not the only one with this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26305718/15862).

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to obtain a schema definition programatically? That way I'd know the limits of each column in advance, so I could manually truncate it to its maximum length

Comment: `select character_maximum_length from information_schema.columns where table_schema='pg_temp_2' and table_name='test' and table_column='t';`

Comment: Many thanks, your comment gave me the information I needed